# fill the missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dates like that :

```
    my_dates_list = ['10/10/2010','17/10/2010','17/10/2010','12/10/2010','10/10/2010',
'17/11/2007','17/10/2021','11/10/2017']
```

Need: I want to fill the missing dates and count the occurrence of each date,
the need is already satisfied by counting the occurrence

```
'17/11/2007' 1
'10/10/2010' 2
'17/10/2010' 2
'12/10/2010' 1
'11/10/2017' 1
'17/10/2021' 1
```

and I also managed to fill the missing dates, but I fill all the missing date's day by day, what i wanna to try is just add the day before and after to have something like this

```
'16/11/2007' 0
'17/11/2007' 1
'18/11/2007' 0
'09/10/2010' 0
'10/10/2010' 2
'11/10/2010' 0
'16/10/2010' 0
'17/10/2010' 2
'18/10/2010' 0
'11/10/2010' 0
'12/10/2010' 1
'13/10/2010' 0
'10/10/2017' 0
'11/10/2017' 1
'12/10/2017' 0
'16/10/2021' 0
'17/10/2021' 1
'18/10/2021' 0
```

I just need clarification because I take much time to fill all the date's day by day thank you

Comment: is Pandas required for this?

Comment: no but it should be the fastest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running this to generate what you are looking for:

```py
import collections
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

my_dates_list = ['10/10/2010','17/10/2010','17/10/2010','12/10/2010','10/10/2010',
'17/11/2007','17/10/2021','11/10/2017']

# Count and aggregate number of occurrences within my_dates_list
counter_ref = collections.Counter(my_dates_list)
my_dates_list_agg = set((date, counter_ref[date]) for date in my_dates_list)

# Convert your datetime strings to datetime objects
datetimes = [(datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), agg) for date, agg in my_dates_list_agg]
# Get dates 1 day before
datetimes_day_before = [(dttm - timedelta(days=1), 0) for dttm, _ in datetimes]
# Get dates 1 day after
datetimes_day_after = [(dttm + timedelta(days=1), 0) for dttm, _ in datetimes]
# Flatten a list of nested tuples into one continuous list of tuples
# Also convert datetime objects to string representation found in my_dates_list
datetimes_total = [(dttm.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), agg) for dttm_group in zip(datetimes_day_before, datetimes, datetimes_day_after) for dttm, agg in dttm_group]

print(datetimes_total)
```

Comment: solved my problem after i changed list to set thank you